# Why the Longman dictonary doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dictionary

I installed the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), it's completely installed; but when I want to run it, nothing happens.

also in terminal generates this error :

```
./ldoce5-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and after try :

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk1.2
```

generates this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgtk1.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk1.2'
```

why?

Comment: Does starting it command line throw any errors?

Comment: @Rinzwind; thnx but (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/ia32-libs/download) has several dependency, could you please tell me how can I install it ?!

Comment: Not with 100% certainty without installing ubuntu 64 on my machine but you probably need those all...

Comment: is there any way to install all of them with a command ? one command I mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem finally fixed by this package and Longman Dictionary worked perfectly  :)

```
apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```

Thnx a lot ...